# Angular script is not binding the json response

Tags: c#, android, rest, service

I have a subscription in angular for a rest api
code is like below :-

component.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
  this.txt="Connecting jayapen.com"  
  this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(data => {    
    this.httpData=data;})
  }
```

component.html

```
 <tr *ngFor="let datas of httpData">
    <td>{{datas.ID}}</td>
    <td>{{datas.Uname}}</td>
  </tr>
```

This is my API Link
http://jayapen.com/rest/details.svc/GetAllUsers

No data is binding from the above link .

But for the api link https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos , i am getting the data

Please help !

Comment: you sure want to have user info available to unauthorized user at public end-point?

Comment: i dindt understand it clearly

Comment: I meant your end-point at  http://jayapen.com/rest/details.svc/GetAllUsers reveals user information without any secure, E.g, I could also check who your users and what their passwords are. (Not an issue if you're just playing around with dummy test data). And btw, could you please create test project on stackblitz?

Comment: I created stackblitz for you that would just log the response (or error) based on the end-point you call, you can try that out here --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-si8nut?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts, just replace targetUrl in app.component.ts and you'll see the difference in response. Your end-point errors for some reason, perhaps you need to configure CORS on your back-end.

Comment: i configured CORS , still its not working, why my json response is not well formated ?

Comment: I think the problem may be in C# code (or whatever code handles your API).  Can you post your CORS details here?